# How to replace multiple forward slashes in a directory by a single slash?

Tags: python, string, path

My path:

```
'/home//user////document/test.jpg'
```

I want this to be converted into:

```
'/home/user/document/test.jpg'
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`os.path.abspath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) or [`normpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) to canonicalise the path:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.abspath('/home//user////document/test.jpg')
'/home/user/document/test.jpg'
```

Answer (score 5):

**Solution:**
This code snippet should solve your issue:

```
import re
x = '/home//user////document/test.jpg'
re.sub('/+','/', x)
```

**Output:**

```
'/home/user/document/test.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution is very simple by using Regex.
You can use it 're' module of the Python standard library.

```py
import re

old_path = '/home//user////document/test.jpg'
converted_path = re.sub('/+', '/', old_path)
```

I'm sorry not to speak English fluently ;)

Comment: While your identifiers are better, this solution was already given by Piyush Sambi. So better comment on that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating a [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) object from your string will remove redundant slashes automatically for you:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('/home//user////document/test.jpg')
print(path)
# /home/user/document/test.jpg
```

Comment: Not accurate. `str(Path("c:\\\\test\\\\"))` yields 'c:\\test'

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way is to replace `'//'` with `'/'` twice:

```py
a = '/home//user////document/test.jpg'

a.replace('//', '/').replace('//', '/')
```

Comment: And what if you have `//////`?

Comment: @deceze if that is the case, this won't work. I didn't interpret the question as needing to work with an arbitrary number of slashes...